# Uppercase to lowercase string

Tags: c++, string, char, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to convert lowercase to uppercase by using only string and char values. This gets a stranger error saying:
Error   C2678   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    Win32Project18  c:\users\leeanntop\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\win32project18\win32project18\source.cpp   11
The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>




using namespace std;
int main()
{
     const char a = a;
     char capital = a - 32;
     cout << "Please input your chosen lowercase letter " ;
     cin >> a;
     cout << "Your capital letter is : " << capital << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, think about what is needed to make something a char.

Comment: const char a = a;  ???? 
Did you try just with char a = '';

Comment: thank you. just char a works fine so far. now I'm just trying to do this for all input values of the letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

`const` means you can't change it.

Therefore `cin` can't put anything in it. You need just `char`.

Also `char a = a;` doesn't make any sense, so just remove the `= a` or do something like `= 'a';`, and setting `capitol` needs to be done after getting a character from `cin`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do this:

```
int main()
{
     char a = '';
     cout << "Please input your chosen lowercase letter " ;
     cin >> a;
     char capital = toupper(a);
     cout << "Your capital letter is : " << capital << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks for your response. Only problem is the compiler won't let me input the '' with nothing in it as a statement.

Comment: Are you sure? then try to put something dummy, like char a='a';

Comment: That works fine ^^;. I tried that before, and am currently working on getting it to work for all letters, since it'll only return an uppercase A so far.

Comment: Still returns only uppercase A, for now.

Comment: I don't know... maybe you forgot to compile again. Btw: I don't know why someone puts me a downvote